# How To Update Many Mongo Documents Node.js async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have the async function below. DeviceStatus is a Mongo Collection of devices which has the property SerialNumber defined. Here, I'm collecting an array of of all devices in the DeviceStatus Collection and then iterating through each of them. I'd like to add a new property called NumberOfRetries and set it to zero. The function below works for the first DeviceStatus document. That is, in the loop it updates the document and adds the NumberOfRetries for the first document but does not complete the update for the remaining documents. Does anyone know what changes are required here so that I'm able to update all Mongo documents in the DeviceStatus collection.

```
static async addNumberOfRetriesCap(){
        const devices = await DeviceStatus.find().exec();
        for(let i = 0; i < devices.length; i++){
            let device = devices[i];
            await DeviceStatus.updateOne({"SerialNumber": device.SerialNumber}, {$set: {"NumberOfRetries" : "0"}})
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the $in operator and updateMany functionality.

```
const addNumberOfRetriesCap = async() => {
    const devices = await DeviceStatus.find({}, {
        SerialNumber: true
    }).exec();
    let deviceSerialNumber = []
    for (let i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) deviceSerialNumber.push(devices[i].SerialNumber)
    await DeviceStatus.updateMany({
        "SerialNumber": {
            $in: deviceSerialNumber
        }
    }, {
        $set: {
            "NumberOfRetries": "0"
        }
    })
}
```

If you want to update all values of the collection DeviceStatus you can direclty update the db like in the following example

```
const addNumberOfRetriesCap = async() => {
    await DeviceStatus.updateMany({}, {
        $set: {
            "NumberOfRetries": "0"
        }
    })
}
```